# How do I keep WZZIP from creating a zip that makes a folder when unzipped?

Tags: batch-file, winzip

I'm looking at an automated process (utilizing a "DOS" .BAT file) that creates zip files with a simple command like...

```
wzzip [path][zip file name] [files to be zipped]
```

> <sup>"[files to be zipped]" above is just a list of files, local to
>   the current directory, with no path info specified, like: `File1.txt File2.txt File3.txt`</sup>

...but when a partner receives and unzips these files, it's creating a folder with the name of the zip file and putting the files inside it, and they need (well, or at least prefer) it to just extract the files to the `.` folder.

Is there a way to get wzzip to use `.` instead of creating an eponymous folder? The only thing I could see in the options list was to maybe hack something out of `-r-p` (even though I DON'T actually want it to recurse folders when zipping), but I was hoping there might be a better way.

The partner company is apparently running Linux, so while I see that wzunzip has an option to set the output folder that MIGHT override the default behavior, I'm not sure what the app they are using might allow.

Comment: What's the actual command arguments you're using to create the zip?  If the 'files to be zipped' is just a folder (e.g.: drive:\folder), change it to "drive:\folder\*.*" and try again.

Comment: Russ, it looks like your editing problem is that you created a second user ID.  You can freely edit your own posts but for your own protection, it needs to be done using the original user account.  This will also interfere with your ability to comment on your own thread, accept an answer, and accumulate rep.  See http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts to get your accounts merged.  That will fix the problem.

Comment: @RussPerryJr - Even though you are the author ( granted you your actually using a second user account ) your edits are still invalid.  Excellll is correct to remove the noise you have added to your question.

Comment: @RussPerryJr: And by the way, the rules for Super User are pretty much the same as the rules for Stack Overflow — you'll be able to [edit], comment on and accept answers to your question, once you authenticate that it is ***your*** question.  Ideally, you should do that by using the account that owns the question.  If you can no longer access that first account, merge your accounts by going to the [contact form](http://superuser.com/contact) and selecting “I need to merge user profiles”.

Comment: Just a follow-up--were you able to get your accounts straightened out?  You should be able to reply in a comment if everything is working for you.

Comment: Yes, evidently, though I wasn't able to immediately (it claimed my accounts were ALREADY merged).  Better now.

@Techie007: Please see the extra info above.